# Вывод значений из перегруженной операции

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Проблема заключается в том что результат после операций `A+B` и `A-B` не выводится на экран. Код:

```
#include <iostream>

class multiplicity
{
private:
    int size;
    int* array;
public:
    //стандартный конструктор
    multiplicity()
    {
        size = 15;
        array = new int[15];
        for (int i = 0; i<15; ++i)
        {
            array[i] = rand() % 10;
        }
    };
    //конструктор с опредленным размером множетсва
    multiplicity(const int inputSize)
    {
        array = (int*)calloc(inputSize, sizeof(int));
        size = inputSize;
    };
    //конструктор копий
    multiplicity(const multiplicity& CopyMult)
    {
        if (CopyMult.array != NULL)
        {
            array = new int[CopyMult.size];
            for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
            {
                array[i] = CopyMult.array[i];
            }
        }
        else
            array = NULL;
    }
    //конструктор повышающий производительность, он же конструктор перемещения
    multiplicity(multiplicity&& MoveMult)
    {
        if (MoveMult.array != NULL)
        {
            array = MoveMult.array;
            MoveMult.array = NULL;
        }
    }
    //деструктор
    ~multiplicity()
    {
        if (array != NULL)
            delete[] array;
    }

    void add() const
    {
        int inputInt;
        std::cin >> inputInt;
        for (int i = 0; i<size;++i)
        {
            if (array[i] == 0)
            {
                array[i] = inputInt;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void show() const
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)
                std::cout << array[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    };

    friend const multiplicity operator+(const multiplicity& left, const multiplicity& right)
    {

        multiplicity newMult(left.size);
        for (int i = 0; i<left.size; ++i)
        {
            newMult.array[i] = left.array[i];
        }
        int newsize = right.size;
        for (int i = 0; i < right.size; ++i)
        {
            if (newMult.array[i] != right.array[i])
            {
                newMult.array = (int*)realloc(newMult.array, sizeof(int));
                newsize++;
                newMult.array[newsize - 1] = right.array[i];
            }

        }
        return  newMult;
    }

    friend const  multiplicity operator-(const multiplicity& left, const multiplicity& right)
    {
        int newsize = left.size;

        multiplicity newMult(left.size);
        for (int i = 0; i < left.size; ++i)
        {
            newMult.array[i] = left.array[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < right.size; ++i)
        {
            if (newMult.array[i] == right.array[i])
            {
                for (int j = i - 1; j < newMult.size; ++j)
                {
                    newMult.array[j] = newMult.array[j + 1];
                }
            }
        }
        return newMult;
    }

};

int main()
{
    multiplicity A;
    multiplicity B;

    A.show();
    B.show();

    int k;
    std::cin >> k;
    if (k == 1)
    {
        multiplicity D = A + B;
        D.show();
    }

    if (k == 2)
    {
        multiplicity C = A - B;
        C.show();
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проблема заключается в том что результат после операций A+B и A-B не выводиться на экран

Comment: Запустите под отладчиком и посмотрите в чем дело.

Comment: Скомпилировал. Все выводиться. Есть подозрение, что k либо не вводите, либо оно читается с потолка и не равно 1 или 2.

Answer (score 2):

Начинаю ругаться...

Не смешивайте ни в коем случае `new` и `calloc/realloc`!

Аргумент `const int` - `const` явно излишнее...

В конструкторе копирования кто будет `size` инициализировать? Дейкстра? А в перемещающем - Вирт? :)

`delete` спокойно работает с нулем, проверка не нужна.

А вообще - я так и не врубился, что у вас делается в операторах `+` и `-` - поясните нормальными словами, пожалуйста...

Comment: еще NULL вместо nullptr